# Unknown database 'database'

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I am trying to make a secure login for my database, using a MySQL database.

```
Private Sub logIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles logIn.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
            "server=localhost;userid=root;password=Catawba;database=catawbapartnership"
        Dim READER As MySqlDataReader


        Try
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "select * from database.admininfo where admin_username= ' " & TB_UN.Text & " ' and admin_password= ' " & TB_PD.Text & " '"
            COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
            READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
            Dim count As Integer
            count = 0
            While READER.Read
                count = count + 1
            End While

            If count = 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password Accepted")
            ElseIf count > 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password Are Incorrect")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password Are Incorrect")
            End If

            MysqlConn.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()

        End Try`
```

This is the code, but I keep getting the error of Unknown database'database'

In MySQL Workbench, the entire database is named catawbapartnership
And the table I need to get info from is called admininfo

But, it keep saying I have entered it incorrectly. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `database.` from your code. As a default database is in the connection you don't need to specify it in the question.

Please copy your implementation from somewhere else. This has SQL injection vulnerabilities and you should never store plain text passwords.

[OWASP](https://owasp.org/) has a lot of guidance on being a responsible programmer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I apologize for this mistake, it is my first time using it here.

Comment: I removed the database. from my code, but I still keep getting the same error